# [E2007][EWSMA] Identify/get the reason/cause of a NDR

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I need to parse NDRs and identify their cause(the reason why the email wasn't delivered). If it was due to an invalid email or invalid domain or mailbox full or another.

Is there a way to do it without having to parse the email body which isn't the most full proof way...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have to parse the message body to get to the status code indicating why the email could not be delivered.  See this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232118%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) for more details on Delivery Status, NDRs and status codes.